# jQuery slideToggle - Don't push content, hide content and fill parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 card and I want the card header to act as a slide toggle - When you click the header it should slide down a div to fill the height and width of the card div, and also not push down the card, and hide the original card content with its own content.
The problem is that everything I try solves one problem but not the other: For example I can make it not push down content with absolute positioning, but then its content will be hidden behind the card content, or not fill the card

This is something close to what I want:

```js
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".flip").click(function () {                  
                    $(this).siblings(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
                });
            });
```

```css
            .panel, .flip {
                padding: 5px;
                text-align: center;
                background-color: #e5eecc;
                border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
            }

            .panel {
                
                padding: 50px;
                display: none;
                
            }
            .flip{
                    cursor:pointer;

            }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="card text-center">
            <div class="card-header flip">      
                Card Header - Click Me
            </div>
            <div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some card text here.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="card-footer text-muted">
               Footer
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You can moderate overlap behind / front  using `z-index`. Have you tested this?

Comment: this partially solves it: Because now the panel starts to slide from above the header, I want it to slide down right below the header (like in the snippet) - it does solve the problem of hiding content though, it's getting closer. Also it is not the same width as the card (Whereas I want it both to be same width - and height, i.e completely fill the card)

Comment: Ok. So you can add `top:50px` to force it start 50px from top. If you present your code for absolute position, I could write the complete solution.

Comment: It doesn't have to be solved with absolute, I used it because this worked for me as to prevent the push down behavior. Of course if you can solve it with absolute it will be great (or if there is any other way to simply make my snippet not push down content and fill the card it would also be great)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution using absolute positioning with some changes. I have used relative position for card so the panel be absolute to it (not to the whole document). Also used fixed height for `.card-body` and `.panel` to make their heights equal. If you hate fixed height, you may use a javascript to make their height equal after DOM ready. Also if you have multiple cards on a page, You may need also define a certain height for each card because the relative position does not occupy a place in the document.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                $(".flip").click(function () {                  
                    $(this).siblings(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
                });
            });
```

```css
.panel, .flip {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e5eecc;
    border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;

}

.panel {
    padding: 50px;
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    top:50px;
    width:100%;
    height:160px;
}

.flip{
  cursor:pointer;
}

.card-body{
height:160px
}

.card{
position:relative;
top:0;left:0
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="card text-center">
            <div class="card-header flip">      
                Card Header - Click Me
            </div>
            <div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some card text here.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="card-footer text-muted">
               Footer
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This is excatly what I needed! Now will have to figure out the correct sizing for my cards, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Max-height property is what you need. Here's what I made with your code. I edited your DOM-tree a bit, but it works like what you described! :) Or maybe I've misunderstood your problem.

```js
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".flip").click(function () {                  
                    $(this).siblings(".card-content").find(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
                });
            });
```

```css
            .panel, .flip{
                padding: 5px;
                text-align: center;
                background-color: #e5eecc;
                border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
            }
            .panel{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                display: none;
            }
            .card-content{
                overflow: hidden;
                max-height: 180px;
            }
            .card-body{
                width:100%;
                height:180px;
            }
            .flip{
                cursor:pointer;
            }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="card text-center">
            <div class="card-header flip">      
                Card Header - Click Me
            </div>
            
            <div class="card-content">
                <div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some card text here.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="card-footer text-muted">
               Footer
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: In your snippet the slide panel still pushes the content down and doesn't fill and cover the card, I wanted what Ali Sheikhpour did. But thank you!